# How can I create ISOs quickly using all 16 cores of a Parallella board?

Tags: iso, multi-core

I have a large video collection (over 900 disks). Using Handbrake to rip to .mp4 is painfully slow, especially when ripping BRD. I found another solution that will play back ISOs, but I want to be able to do this very quickly.  How can I get Ubuntu, running on a 16-core Parallella board, to use all cores to get the job done FAST?

Answer (score 0):

Video conversion is not something that scales out that well and I strongly suspect it's not something that the Parallella board is going to excel at. The best encoding needs a big beefy CPU and a lot of time.

I've just done all the sums. To do this you would need:

- 450+ hours of your time to extract raw video from discs
- ~$3k in AWS compute time (using their elastic transcoder), including transfer via disks

Or you could do it at home on demand but a 1KW computer taking ~2hours a go... That's an additional 1800 hours (just over two months) and £226 in electricity.

I think a much better solution is to find the most [local disc ripping service](http://www.digiraw.com/disc-to-digital-ripping-service/dvd-ripping-services.html). That one will charge £1 a disc. Sure that's over a grand once you factor in your storage (a couple of 4TB drives should do it), but it's only 30 minutes of your time while you send it.

---

As for making ISOs, you're still in the position of extracting everything... Which again, is 450+ hours of disk juggling and waiting for data to transfer. If your time isn't worth anything, that might be okay but CPU time isn't the limiting factor here, it's transfer speed between the optical drive and hard disk.

If you're willing to sink that much time in, I'd go with something like MakeMKV which will convert the disk into a MKV video without any re-encoding. That is again something that won't benefit from many CPUs but most modern hardware network players can handle MKVs so it's a lot more useful than an ISO.

But as I say, any operation that involves you feeding 900 disks to a computer is going to require a few months of your time (years if you don't focus on it).

Comment: You do not understand.  I would be coverting the DVDs and Blu-rays directly to ISOs. What I need is the way to quickly covert the disk to ISO.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger I'd go with MakeMKV for any video extraction (it lets you leave out the junk and is the only tool I know that can handle AACS video on Ubuntu) but while it's quick, it's still half an hour for each video and when you have 900 items to process, you're talking serious pain.

Comment: You could probably automate most of it with enough concentration but it's going to require something [like this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qfraqofgHTY) and some mad programming skills.